# Error forms django no valid with post

Tags: python, django, forms

I unable to store the data in my database, I have an error message when I click on the button 'validate' =form invalid

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime


class automobile(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    mail=models.CharField(max_length=256,default='NULL', blank = True,null=True)
    investissement=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank = True,null=True)
    telephone =models.IntegerField(blank = True, null =True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lastname + ' ' + self.firstname
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from autoroute.models import automobile
from django import forms
from datetime import date
import datetime

class automobileF(forms.Form):
        lastname = forms.CharField(label="Votre Nom (*)" )
        firstname = forms.CharField(label="Votre Prénom(*)")
        mail=forms.CharField(label = "Votre adresse mail (*)" )
        investissement=forms.IntegerField(label = "Votre investissement (*)")
        telephone =forms.IntegerField(label="votre numéro de téléphone (*)")
```

my function is like this :

```
def automobile(request):
    response={}
    from automobile.views import automobileF
    if request.method=='POST':
       formset=automobileF(request.POST)
       if formset.is_valid():
           try:
               contact=automobile.objects.get(lastname=form.cleaned_data['lastname'])
               return HttpResponseRedirect('frontend/return_automobile.html')
           except:
               contact=automobile(lastname=form.cleaned_data['lastname'])
               contact.firstname=form.cleaned_data['firstname']
               contact.mail=form.cleaned_data['mail']
               contact.telephone=form.cleaned_data['telephone']
               contact.investissement=form.cleaned_data['investissement']
               contact.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('frontend/success_automobile.html')
       else:
           return HttpResponse('form invalid')
    else:
        return render (request,'frontend/automobile.html',response)
    return render (request,'frontend/automobile.html',{'formset': formset})
```

automobile.html

```
 <div class="row">
                            <div class="span10">
                             <form method="POST" role="form" action ="/automobile/"> {% csrf_token %}

<label style="color:#000000;margin-top:10px"><strong> Votre nom (*)</strong></label>
<input type="text"  name="lastname" value="{{formset.lastname}}"  >

<label style="color:#000000;margin-top:10px"><strong> Votre prenom (*)</strong></label>
<input type="text"  name="firstname" value="{{formset.firstname}}" >


<label style="color:#000000;margin-top:10px"><strong> Votre adresse mail (*) </strong></label>
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="address" value="{{formset.mail}}" >



<label style="color:#000000;margin-top:10px"><strong> investissement (*) </strong></label>
<input type="text" class="input-small" name="zip_code" value="{{formset.investissement}}" >



<label style="color:#000000;margin-top:10px"><strong> Numéro de telephone (*) </strong</label>
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="{{formset.telephone}}" >

<p style="text-align:center"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Validate</button> </p>
                            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

someone has an idea on how to solve the problem

Comment: What does the title "Error forms django no valid with post" mean? Is this the exact error you get? If not what error message do you get? Please clarify a bit.

Comment: when I click on the "submit" button, it triggers the exception return HttpResponse('form invalid') and it appears "form invalid"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please don't call your form variable "formset": it's not a formset, it's a form.

Secondly, Django is validating your form for you nicely, but you are not sending it back to the template to display any errors. Get rid of the first `else` clause, and let the execution fall through to the last line so that the form is sent to the template. Then, make sure you show `{{ formset.errors }}` in your template, or display the errors individually alongside the fields themselves.

(Also, please learn how to use CSS classes rather than inline styles in your HTML.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I deleted the requirement else, I added {{formset.errors}} in the template but nothing is displayed, this is normal?